# Is there anyway to test iPod Library for iPhone 5 wihout Physical devices?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I don't have `iPhone 5` but i have `iPod4.`

Now i am doing custom Music app.

for testing i am fine with my iPod4.

However when i want to test for iPhone5,i can't test it because of iPod Library.

Simulator doesn't support iPod Library.

So i want to know is there anyway to test it or not?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simple answer to your question NO